# On Ubuntu 18.04 what is the way to remove dnsmasq and systemd-resolved and switch to resolv.conf

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

I noticed that with introduction with the combo of systemd-resolved and dnsmasq in Ubuntu 18.04 network connectity is becoming a luxury feature.

What is the correct way to remove these components in Ubuntu 18.04 so we can end up with a tried and tested means of having some network connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

The default service using port 53 is systemd-resolved, to disable it the option is:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

If you also need to disable dnsmasq the option is:

```
sudo systemctl disable dnsmasq
sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq
```